# dropdownlist not selecting the correct index

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, html-select

I have a database bound dropdown list that gets its values from a DB.

When I call the ddl.SelectedItem either .Text or .Value the index is incorrect.

Let's say the values in the DB tables are like so:

```
Column1 | Column2

Dublin1 | Value1
Dublin2 | Value1
Dublin3 | Value1
London1 | Value2
London2 | Value2
London3 | Value2
```

SQL select query:

```
SELECT [Column1],[Column2] FROM [Table] ORDER BY [Column1]
```

The DDL:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" 
 DataSourceID="SQLDataSource" DataTextField="Column1" 
 DataValueField="Column2"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Binding on ASPX only:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDataSource" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString %>" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT [Column1],[Column2],FROM [Table] ORDER BY [Column1]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So when I get the Selected Item from the dropwdownlist whether I pick Dublin2 or Dublin3, it always comes back with Dublin1, same with London values.

The ddl populates correctly for both item.text and item.value.

Is there something I need to set regarding the bounding?

Comment: Could you add the server side code with the `ddl.SelectedItem`?

Comment: Are the TextItems and ValueItems unique?

Comment: well, this seems pretty odd, we can help you if you provide more server side code :)

Comment: `SELECT [Column1],[Column2] FROM [Table] ORDER BY [Column1]` Is this gives correct value or you get duplicate?

Comment: U have to clear the selected items

Comment: Its like dddl.items.clear();     Try this........

Comment: Updated code above. I am not binding in code behind at all currently. The binding is from the aspx page.

Comment: Where do I clear them?

Comment: My Column2 values are not all unique. Column1 values are. Apparently that can cause an issue: http://forums.asp.net/t/1218292.aspx/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the values in the dropdown must be unique and the `Column2` has repeated values. You should modify the databind to use `Column1` on both text and value:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" 
 DataSourceID="SQLDataSource" DataTextField="Column1" 
 DataValueField="Column1"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then on code behind access you need a copy of a table and access it like this to get the value:

```
Dictionary<string, string> table = //Get the table here with Column1 as keys    
table[ddl.SelectedItem.Value]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking for IsPostBack inside Page_Load .

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{  
    BindDropDownListddl();      
}
```

Also set AutoPostBack to true for your drop down list.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" 
 DataSourceID="SQLDataSource" DataTextField="Column1" 
 DataValueField="Column2" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
```